# update data to postgres database through datagridview using npgsql

Tags: c#, datagridview, npgsql

I am having trouble to update my data from datagridview edit using npgsql.

```
protected NpgsqlConnection dataconnect = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=cpdatabase;Password=5622;Database=cpdb;");
protected DataSet dset = new DataSet("maindata.sessions");
protected NpgsqlDataAdapter NpAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
```

Below code loads data into datagridview on form load.

```
string crossref = "Select * from maindata.sessions where \"DATE:\" BETWEEN '03-01-2014' and '04-01-2014'";
NpAdapter.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(crossref,this.dataconnect);
NpAdapter.Fill(dset, "sessions");
var dtsource = dset.Tables["sessions"];
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtsource;
```

Below is my update code which doesnot work :

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dtsource.AcceptChanges();
}
```

I have tried lot of different ways to update it but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE sessions SET column1 = @value1, column2 = @value2  WHERE column1 = @value1", this.connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@value1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 12, "column1");
command.Parameters.Add("@value2", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 50, "column2");
NpgsqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@oldvalue1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 12, "column1");
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
NpAdapter.UpdateCommand = command;
NpAdapter.Update(dset,"sessions");
```